# sql/sequelize how to make a complex query involving one-to-many relation

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models, a Session and a Register, with a relation defined as follows:

```js
Session.hasMany(Register, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
Register.belongsTo(Session);
```

I want to get a list of Sessions that the User has registered for, a Register has a foreign key with the User model. With only the UserId how would I get a list of Sessions that have a Register object created by the User?

Comment: I'm willing for a solution written in SQL as well, but just sequelize is preferred.

Comment: there is userId in session model?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your include so that the `user` model includes the `register` which incldes the `session` like the example below:
`models.users.findOne({`
`where: {`
`email: data.email //or any other unique identifier`
`},`
`include: { model: models.register,`
`include: {model: models.sessions}}`
`})`